# How can I Upload small size file using angular2 and spring?

Tags: java, spring, angular2-routing

I am using angular2 and spring to upload file but when i used small size of file than i am getting error are:-

**Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present**

my code are
In angular2 code:-

```
function uploadRecord()
 {    
   var formData = new FormData();
   var record_id = 1234
   formData.append("file", $scope.file); 
   formData.append("record_id",record_id);                                                                                                                            uploadRecordFile.save(formData, function(result) {
     // some code here
   }, onParseError);
  }
```

Code in Resources class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadRecordFile",
method = RequestMethod.POST,
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 @Timed
public boolean uploadRecordFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("record_id") Long id)
        throws Exception {        
        return true;
    }
```

Is there any way to upload all size of files or is there any setting for it?

I am using following bean setting in my config:-

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");           
    return resolver;
}
```

When i remove above mention settings from config than files were uploading but big size files were not uploading as i need this setting i cannot change it so is there any setting from which i can upload both small and big size file?